XHR Data Transfer Between Javascript and PHP

JS dispatch was successful. But it does not enter the if block in PHP. Whereas before I restarted the computer successfully entered the if block in PHP.

When successful, the data received is “1”. Even though I have set the static data sent is “4”.


Javascript code:
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let dataStorage = new FormData();
dataStorage.append('dataStorage', 4);

console.log("Data yang dikirim:", dataStorage.get('dataStorage'));

xhr.open('POST', 'sistemDB.php', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("AJAX request completed with status: " + xhr.status);
        // console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        console.log("AJAX request failed with status: " + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Request failed");
};
xhr.send(dataStorage);
console.log("Send berhasil");

PHP code:
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST); // Display all POST data
    echo '</pre>';

    // Alternative way to check raw POST data
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Raw POST data: ' . file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo '</pre>';

    if (isset($_POST['dataStorage'])) {
        $data = $_POST['dataStorage'];
        echo htmlspecialchars($data); // Use htmlspecialchars to prevent XSS attacks
    } else {
        echo 'dataStorage not set';
    }
}
?>

Please help me
I am trying to change the static value to send to PHP, to a value of "4"
Notes: php and javascript scripts are located in the same file “sistemDB.php”.

Now what is the script file actually named, systemDB.php or sistemDB.php, as you have it in the code? (If mod_speling kicks in here to "correct" such an error, you might be losing your POST data due to the fact that the browser follows a redirect by making a GET request.)

Sorry. script file name is sistemDB.php

What request(s) do you see the browser make, when you inspect this in the network panel of your browser dev tools?

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200

Have you debugged and tested your PHP script? Is the server environment variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] available? What is the content of the superglobal $_POST?

"it does not enter the if block in PHP" - are you sure this problem is then relatd to JS or AJAX in any way? What have oyu tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

it does not enter the if block...which if block? You have more than one

I tried writing echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; and the result is GET

Then it's obvious that you cannot read anything from $_POST, and also obvious that if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") is not matching. Also, if your browser tells you that a POST request was sent, and your browser thinks that a GET request was sent, there's something completely going wrong. Are you sure you've shared the code that is really leading to this situation?

Does it work if you switch to the more modern fetch() function?

Is it possible your server is sending a redirect? Redirects are processed using GET even if the original request was POST.

@Barmar Is there any way to make the browser not redirect?

No, it's not possible AFAIK. If it doesn't follow the redirect, there's no response to process.
